# How to setup a global store Object?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am working with vueify and browserify. I have made an object in my main.js file

```
var store = {
foo: 'bar'
};

var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data(){
    return {
        foo: store
    };
},

components: {
    Login,
    Registration,
    ClassifiedList,
    BusinessRegistration,
    BusinessUpdate,
    UserRegistration,
    ClassifiedForm,

    //  ClassifiedKfzCreateForm,
    // ClassifiedImmobilienCreateForm,
    // ClassifiedImmobilienEditForm,
    // ClassifiedKleinanzeigenCreateForm,
    // ClassifiedJobsCreateForm
}
```

});

Now in my Vue Instance I can use it with foo.store.foo !
But when I am use the store object in an component, the store object is undefined?

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You could attach the store method to the window object like `window.store = {}`. It's worth noting that the ecosystem is more developed for tools like Vue cli that use webpack instead of browserify

Answer (score 10):

Probably the best way to make your store globally available would be to expose it as a plugin.

I wrote a blog post about [how to expose a Vuex store as a plugin for your app](http://blog.toast38coza.me/make-your-vuex-store-globally-available-by-registering-it-as-a-plugin/).

**In a nutshell:**

Create a file which will add your store object to the main `Vue` prototype. Vue provides an `install` hook to make it easy to do this:

`storePlugin.js`:

```
import store from '.'  // this is your store object
export default {  
  store,
  // we can add objects to the Vue prototype in the install() hook:
  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$myStore = store
  }
}
```

And then in `main.js`, you tell it to use your plugin:

```
import storePlugin from './storePlugin'  
Vue.use(storePlugin)
```

You would then, for example, be able to access your store from a component via:

```
this.$myStore
```